# Subscription fees to use blpapi package

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am want to connect/know if there are ways to get Bloomberg data to Python. I see we can connect through blpapi/pdblp package.

So wanted to check what is the pricing for this. Appreciate if anyone can help me here?

Getting ways to connect to Python to get Bloomberg data

Comment: Bloomberg recently increased its pricing to about $30,000 (i.e. 30k USD) per year come January 2023, see e.g. https://www.neugroup.com/bloomberg-terminal-inflation-9-price-hike-on-jan-1-2023/.

Comment: Thanks. THis includes all possible integration. Like even when we integrate in python also, the cost remains same right?

Comment: Actually what i meant is the price for the subscription(through api). The price you mentioned is about bloomberg terminal right

Comment: They are the same - you need to pay the terminal subscription to access the API, which is included in the subscription.

Comment: There’s a big “but” here. Data limits. There are daily and monthly limits per terminal. And of course they don’t tell you what they are, nor do they give you any warning or way of monitoring usage.

Answer (score 3):

Bloomberg has a number of products, which support the real-time API known as the BLP API. This API is a microservice based API. They have microservices for streaming marketdata (//blp/mktdata), requesting static reference (//blp/refdata), contributing OTC pricing (//firm/c-gdco), submitting orders (//blp/emsx), etc etc. The API supports a number of languages including Python, Perl, C++, .NET, etc. The API pattern requires setting up a session where you 'target'/connect to a delivery point. There are several flavours of delivery points depending on what Bloomberg products you buy. For the Bloomberg (Professional) Terminal, you have something called Desktop API (DAPI), they have something called the Server (SAPI), they have something called B-PIPE, another is EMSX. They all present delivery points. They all support the same BLP API.

The Bloomberg Terminal's delivery point is localhost:8194. No Bloomberg Terminal, no localhost delivery point. However, maybe your organisation has bought an Enterprise B-PIPE product, in which case you don't need a Bloomberg Terminal, and the delivery point will sit on at least two servers (IPs), again on port 8194.

So, bottom line, the API library is available and you can develop against it. Problem is, the first few lines of creating a session object and connecting to the end point will fail unless you have a Bloomberg product. There's no sandbox, sadly.

Pricing depends on product, and unfortunately you'll also need to consider your application use-case. As an example, if you're writing a systematic trading application, then the licensing of the Bloomberg (Professional) Terminal will not permit that, however, a B-PIPE will include a licence that will permit that (plus hefty exchange fees if not OTC).

Good luck.